# Changes to template not showing up unless ?reset=1 added to URL

Tags: theme-development

As title states, I added something to a template file:

```
echo '<img src="'. get_site_url() . '/wp-content/themes/enfold/images/leverage.png" />';
```

But on firefox and IE, the addition won't show up on the page unless "?reset=1" is added to the end of the URL. This issue occurs on all pages. If the URL is entered in without that addition, the page loads without the change in place. Can anyone help me out

Answer (score 0):

Whatever type of cache mechanism you're using, look closer at it. Look for something that says "Flush" or "Clear". Click that.

Comment: Agreed. You should be able to disable your caching for logged in users, or possibly specific roles.